# Price sets not showing up

Tags: civievent, price-sets

We use price sets for our events, as we need to have a registration price that is the regular price, one that is the early bird price, and then a third item that is the textbook that you can choose not to purchase (like if you have it already). Price sets have been working fine until this evening. I just went to add one, which was number 380. Adding it worked fine - it's there on the list. But when I go to the event, it is not on the list of price fields that I can add. I tried adding new ones multiple times, but this happened every time. I also noticed that several of our old ones no longer show the event they are linked to on the page where you can edit the configuration for the price set. If you go to the event's tuition tab, sure enough it doesn't list one there.

Any idea what could be causing this? As a temp fix so I could add new events, I'm re-using an old price set.

The screenshots: We replace the word "Event" with "Training, so that is why it says that. The list on the drop-down on the event setup page (screenshot 2) always shows in the order in which they were added as a price set. Nothing shows up after the one for Mesa (was number 379). I've created like 10 more - both cloning current ones and creating new - and they never show on the drop down list.

We're on Drupal and version 4.7.22. Planning a major upgrade soon, but we had to finish another large task first that is about 85% done before I can switch gears to the Civi upgrade.

[image: Listing from the Price Sets admin page]

[image: Listing from the event's drop down list]

Comment: can you add some screenshot of the priceset list, dropdown shown on event page, etc? Make sure the priceset setting has `Event` value enabled for `Used For` field

Comment: Screenshots added with a bit of explanation for them.

Comment: Can you also verify that you can't add these new price sets to any event? ie. an older one - a new one? Just in case it's a quirk with the event set up not the price set.

Comment: Yup, I can't add it to any of them. And like I said, a bunch of events all had their price sets disappear and not be able to add them back in. Thankfully they're events that already happened. And we haven't done anything to change the site - no upgrades or anything. And nothing on the server changed, either.